# Conflict appcompat with sherlock library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I am using the image cropper library cropper and therefore have this gradle:
 compile ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

I have added the exclude as i have included the actionbarsherlock lib too.
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

Now I get the error: 
Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'blubblub'

Comment: ActionBarSherlock has been discontinued for 2+ years. I **strongly** recommend that you move off of it.

Comment: But what is the alternative?

Comment: If your `minSdkVersion` is 11 or higher, just get rid of it, as Android has had native action bar support since then. If your `minSdkVersion` is below 11, you will need to use Google's `appcompat-v7` (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.).

Comment: Do I simple use Fragment instead of SherlockFragment?

Comment: Most likely, you would use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. This is from the `support-v4` library, which will be pulled in automatically when you request `appcompat-v7` as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"> What to do with this?

Comment: Change it to something based off of `Theme.AppCompat` (e.g., `Theme.AppCompat.Light`).

Comment: Then I have to include the AppCompat Lib?

Comment: Correct. That is `appcompat-v7`, as I mentioned in my second comment.